# How to log http request/response body even if OAuth2 validation failed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a requirement to index(log) every `request` and `response` body of a Spring Boot MVC application into Elasticsearch application. I implemented the logging in a filter making it the highest priority(of order 1).

My application is acting as an OAuth2 resource server where it validates token from Auth Server. The problem is if the token validation failed, the request doesn't enter the filter, thus skipping the request and response log indexing part. If the token validation failed, the current logic throw the exception in the part:

```
public class MyJwtAccessTokenConverter extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, Object> decode(String token) {
                   //logic to throw token error
           }
   }
```

I want to index the request and response body even if the token is not validated. How can I do it? Is there any way to put Filter before token validation or any other specific way to log requests and responses?

Edit:
My ResourceServer config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Log4j2
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    public String applicationResourceID;

    @Value(" ${key.config.oauth2.publicKey}")
    private String publicKey;

    @Value("jwt.aes.encrypt.keyValue")
    String jwtAesEncryptionKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "test/**"
                ).permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
                )
                .accessDeniedHandler(
                        (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        authenticationEntryPoint.setExceptionTranslator(oauth2ResponseExceptionTranslator());
        resources.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler = new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
        accessDeniedHandler.setExceptionTranslator(oauth2ResponseExceptionTranslator());
        resources.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

        resources.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .resourceId(applicationResourceID)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        MyJwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new MyJwtAccessTokenConverter(jwtAesEncryptionKey);
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }


    @Bean
    @Profile(value = {"local"})
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    public WebResponseExceptionTranslator oauth2ResponseExceptionTranslator() {
        return new DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator() {

            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {

                try {

                    log.info("Oauth2ExceptionTranslatorConfiguration", e);

                    ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> responseEntity = super.translate(e);
                    OAuth2Exception oAuth2ExceptionBody = responseEntity.getBody();
                    HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();

                    OAuth2Exception myOAuth2Response = OAuth2Exception.create(oAuth2ExceptionBody.getOAuth2ErrorCode(), getMessage(oAuth2ExceptionBody));
                    myOAuth2Response.addAdditionalInformation("message", myOAuth2Response.getMessage());
                    myOAuth2Response.addAdditionalInformation("isSuccess", "false");

                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setAll(responseEntity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());

                    return new ResponseEntity<>(myOAuth2Response, headers, statusCode);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.info("Oauth2ExceptionTranslatorConfiguration", ex);
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(new OAuth2Exception("Error"), null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }

            }
        };
    }

    private String getMessage(OAuth2Exception oAuth2Exception) {
        if (oAuth2Exception instanceof InvalidTokenException) {
            return "Invalid Token";
        } else if (oAuth2Exception instanceof InvalidGrantException) {
            return "Invalid Username or password";
        } else if (oAuth2Exception instanceof InvalidRequestException) {
            return "Invalid Request";
        }

        return oAuth2Exception.getOAuth2ErrorCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the  your filter before the jwt authorization filter? Like http.....addFilterBefore(yourcustomfileter, JwtAuthorizationFilter.class) in your resource server config. Also please share your filter  configs

Comment: @balias actually I couldn't find `JwtAuthorizationFilter` implementation in the project. The project is implemented a bit differently than usual Spring Security. I have updated the ResourceServer config. Could you please look into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution for it. If I put my filter order as `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` with annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`, then it enters before token validation(where I can log request) and exit after all filters/operations where I can log response as well.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use custom exception and ControllerAdvice for this purpose

So my example code like

```
public class CustomJwtAccessTokenConverter extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, Object> decode(String token) {
            Map<String, Object> pieces = null;
    
            try {
               //
            } catch(InvalidTokenException ex) {
                throw new InvalidTokenException("MY CUSTOM MESSAGE");
            }
    
          //
        }
    }
```

And you can alse use `ControllerAdvice` to catch what you want

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class, MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,
      HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class})
  public ResponseEntity<Object> InvalidTokenException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    // log you request and your response
  }
}
```

add HttpServletResponse response if you want response

Hope useful

Comment: Yeah, that might be the solution but I want to log in case of success as well(not only failure). Also, there might be other exceptions beside InvalidTokenException where I want to log the response as well. So, I am searching for a common place to log Request/Response(like filter). I have updated the ResourceServer config. Could you please look into it?